# How to safely store data and DBs on Kubernetes (or similar) on DigitalOcean

Tags: redundancy, distributed-filesystems, kubernetes

It boils down to setting up a private cloud on something like Digital Oceans versus another hosting solution like GCE or AWS.  The latter have redundant data stores that can be safely used as volumes, while the former provides a bigger per-instance storage.

So the question is, how would one set up a redundant distributed storage system on a host like DigitalOcean?

Is there something that goes hand-in-hand with, or work in a similar fashion to K8s?  Or would one have to use something like GlusterFS and then tie that in to K8s?

How would such a solution compare with what Google and Amazon offer?

Bonus question: what are some good forums for these types of discussions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question was posted, DigitalOcean has launched [a replicated block storage service](https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/block-storage-more-space-to-scale/), which sounds like it's what you're looking for.